# Displaying different table values depending on the value of another table/column

Tags: sql

I'm quite new to SQL and generally can find my way with basic stuff, but this time I'm kind of stuck...

I'm trying to retrieve (and display) the different configurations of an online app that are stored in a MSSQL DB.

I have to look at the value of a certain table and column (let's call it "configName.id"), and depending on the value returned (negative, positive, NULL), I have to match it in different tables and display one of 3 options in the same column.

I tried using CASE, but I don't want to display 3 different columns; I want to query different tables, and display the results in a single column. The displayed column name should be "Configuration Name".

In basic algorithm language, this would be:

if (configName.id > 0)
  -> Display the corresponding value from table "a"

if (configName.id < 0)
  -> Invert the value returned to be positive, display the corresponding value from table "b"

else
  -> Display "NULL" as results.

My challenge is that regardless of the results returned from any table, I must display it under my report column "Configuration Name".

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sample data from your different tables would help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this

```
select coalesce(a.value, b.value) as value
from configname left join
     a
     on a.id = configname.id and configname.id > 0 left join
     b
     on b.id = abs(configname.id) and configname.id < 0;
```